# ASP.NET Editable Text Box with Syntax Highlighting

Tags: asp.net, syntax-highlighting, wysiwyg

Here's what I'm trying to do. I'm looking for a WYSIWYG editor or just a plain text-box that will highlight HTML syntax (in ASP.NET). Basically, we have a CMS that allows you to mess with templates for various pages, but right now all of the editable HTML is in a plain, ugly, text box. Does anyone know of an editor that will highlight the synax and allow you to edit it? I've checked out Antipro SyntaxEditor, which seems to be a good highlighting solution, but it's just a highlighter, and not an editor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use [FreeTextBox](http://freetextbox.com/default.aspx) on my dasBlog site.  It seems to work pretty well and has the capabilities you're asking for.

**Update**
Hmm... the version on my own site has a button the toolbar to do syntax highlighting, but that button isn't shown on any the demos available at the link I have gave you.  Just know that it does work, but that you may have to play with the configuration some to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to combine tools. For example, SO combines Markdown with [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) which handles the actual syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com) and they offer open source licensing.